# macOS CBCentralManager state unsupported

Tags: swift, macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm attempting to access bluetooth peripherals on macOS (2017 iMac), however the `CBCentralManager` never seems to enter the `.poweredOn` state.

```
import Cocoa
import CoreBluetooth

class BluetoothManager: NSObject {
  var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
  override init() {
    super.init()
    self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue:nil)
    self.checkState()
  }

  func checkState() {
    print("central state: \(self.centralManager?.state.rawValue ?? -1)")
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(2), execute: {
      self.checkState()
    })
  }
}


extension BluetoothManager: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
  func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .poweredOn:
      print("Power on")
    case .unsupported:
      print("Unsupported")
    default:break
    }
  }
}


@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

  var bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager?

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    self.bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()

  }

  ...

}
```

This will consistently output `Unsupported`, with a console warning

```
[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid
```

I am aware of the `Info.plist` key `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`, which I tried, though I believe that is just for iOS devices.

Am I looking in the wrong direction for managing bluetooth on an iMac? Or is my implementation missing something? I feel like I have covered everything required in the [Core Bluetooth documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH1-SW1).

Answer (score 21):

I believe this was due to having the `App Sandbox` enabled (found in the project `Capabilities`).

Enabling `Bluetooth` (under `Hardware`), and accepting the auto changes to entitlements file resolved the issues.

Also disabling the `App Sandbox` seems to work, however I'm not knowledgeable enough to know if this is safe to do.

For reference, my entitlements file now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">  
<plist version="1.0">   
<dict>  
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.bluetooth</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
</dict> 
</plist>
```

Comment: This helped me along, thanks!

Comment: You wil also have to add to your plist; example;<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Our app uses bluetooth to find, connect and transfer data between different devices</string>